# Is there any way to route to a html file with Vue 3 router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3. I need to link a landing page static html page to home route `/` which totally different from vue 3 original `index.html`. The HTML file contains lots of 3rd party CDN stylesheets and scripts. How I load a static html page on any route which is totally different from `index.html` using vue 3?

Comment: Do you have a code example of what you tried so far?

Comment: You misidentified the problem. Vue app with a router is SPA. It won't load another html file when navigating through a router. In order to do this, there should be `location.href` redirect or `<a href` link at some point.